# How can I get the most liked tweet from a search result with Twitter4j?

Tags: java, twitter4j

I have tried using `Collections.sort()` to try sorting the list of tweets I got from searching in Twitter4j but it couldn't work because it doesn't sort based on a property (e.g `listItem.getFavoriteCount()`). Is there any way I can get the most "favourited" tweet with Twitter4j?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, the Twitter Search API, which is used by twitter4j, does not allow ordering tweets. Check the documentation [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets).

However, you can sort the `Status` (tweets) objects after retrieval according to a specific criteria using `Collections.sort(...)`. To do so, you can implement a `Comparator` and use it with [`Collections.sort(tweets, myComparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)).

The code to sort by favourite count could be for example:

```
QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
Collections.sort(result.getTweets(), new Comparator<Status>() {
           @Override
           public int compare(Status status1, Status status2) {
                    return Integer.compare(status2.getFavouriteCount(), status1.getFavouriteCount());
           }
});
```

Hope this helps.